# Clicking submit on a new contact form does nothing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, contacts

I am creating a contact form for a ruby app, and upon filling the form and clicking submit, nothing happens, no refresh or anything. below is the contacts controller file, the routes file, and the html file associated with the form.

**Controller File**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

        if @contact.save
            redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: 'Message sent.'
        else
            redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: 'Error occured.'
        end 
    end

    private
        def contact_params
            params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
        end
end
```

**Routes File**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :contacts
    get '/about' => 'pages#about'
    root 'pages#home'
```

**HTML File**

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class='well'
            <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :name %>
                  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :email %>
                  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= f.label :comments %>
                  <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>
                <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your Rails log show, and what does your Javascript console show? Could you provide snippets of both in the body of your question? Also, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Do you have an `end` in your routes.rb? + same request as @JoshBrody

Answer (score 0):

it seems nothing wrong but could you use `<button>` tag to see what happen?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, and it turns out that I just need to learn to read better and pay closer attention to my code. In the HTML file, my third  down with the class 'well' was missing the '>'. Thank you for the answers and trying to help, I just need to get better at looking at my own code.